# Using homology, show that if $ f : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a homeomorphism then m=n

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am taking a topology course this semester and this question was left as an exercise in my class.

> Question: If $f: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a homeomorphism then show that m=n using homology.

I am not sure on how exactly I should use homology to prove what is asked.

Edit 1: I found a proof in class notes of a senior which goes like:f induces a homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^n $/{0} onto $\mathbb{R}^n $/ {f(0)} but $\mathbb{R}^m $/{0}~ $S^{m-1}$  and $\mathbb{R}^n $/{0} ~ $S^{n-1}$. Then $H_{n-1} (\mathbb{R}^m $/{0}) $=R$ . So, we should have $H_{m-1} (\mathbb{R}^n $/{0}) =R . But this is only possible when m=n.

*But I  have following questions in the proof: (1)  How does $\mathbb{R}^m $/{0}  is homotopic to  $S^{m-1}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n $/{0} is homotopic to  $S^{n-1} $. If I prove this then I know that both $S^{n-1}$ and $S^{m-1}$ are homotopic to a point and also  Rest of the proof is clear to me.*

Can you please outline a proof?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: a homeomorphism $f\colon A \to B$ induces isomorphisms in all homology groups $f_* \colon H_k(A) \to H_k(B)$. Use this with $A = \Bbb R^m \setminus \{0\}$ and $B = \Bbb R^n \setminus \{f(0)\}$, which retracts to some suitable topological spaces.

Comment: @Didier Can you please prove how a homeomorphism $f:A \to B$ induces isomorphism in all homology  groups. And can you please write a detailed answer?

Comment: @Didier f induces a homeo of $\mathbb{R}^n $\{0} onto $\mathbb{R}^n $\ {f(0)}

Comment: No, from $\Bbb R^m \setminus \{0\}$ (not $\Bbb R^n\setminus \{0\}$) onto $\Bbb R^n\setminus \{f(0)\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

What I like to do is take the *one-point compactifications*, $S^m$ and $S^n$.  It's easy to see that a homeomorphism from $\Bbb R^m$ to $\Bbb R^n$ induces a homeomorphism of $S^m$ and $S^n.$

However,  since $S^m$ and $S^n$ have different homology,  we are done.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering.  But it is not easy at all for me to see how  a homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n $ induces an homeomprphism  of $S^m $ and $S^n$ and also can you please give a reference of the results $S^m$ and $S^n$ have different homology.

Comment: Did you look up "one-point compactification"?  Also it's one of the most important examples,  $H_i(S^n)=\begin {cases}0\,,i\neq0,n\\\Bbb Z,\,i=0,n\end {cases}.$  You should be able to find it in almost any beginning algebraic topology book.  Like Greenberg and Harper or Munkres.

Comment: The one-point compactification of $\Bbb R^n$ is $S^n$.  Or, $\Bbb R^n$ is the sphere with a point removed.

Comment: @hawaiianearringroup thank you very much for answering!

Comment: @hawaiianearringgroup I like your proof very much. However, I'm not sure that it's *easy* to see that $f$ induces an homeomorphism between the compactifications: there are a few (not so complicated) things to say first about what happens at infinity for an homeomorphism

Comment: Thanks.   My advisor was impressed by it too.   It was on the Qual.  He told me so, since he helped grade it. @Didier